# How to resize SwiftUI visionOS window based on the size of a text view?

Tags: swift, swiftui, visionos

I'm streaming back text from an AI service and the response will come back buffered. The text can shift between being a decent amount to a little amount. I found this video online of another VisionOS app that does translations where his window grows and shrinks based off of the text coming in. I've included a short gif showing that video below where you can see once it starts, the text shrinks and the window shrinks and then grows up to 4 lines and then fades off at top.

When my text ends up being more than my window size, it gets "..." appended to it and it stops updating. It doesn't increase the screen size. I would like something very similar if not exactly the same as that video where the window expands and shrinks based off the text inside up to 4 lines. Bonus points if the latest text updates are on the bottom and the top fades off as I'm not sure at all how to do that as well.

I've tried using minheight and maxheight frames on text and stack but that didn't change anything. Adding fixed size made the text flow up so that the bottom text was always new and the old text got pushed up but it started to push up past the window height so it got "cropped" off the top as opposed to pushing the window.

I've included a condensed version of what I have below.

[image: Resizing Vision Pro window]

```
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ZStack {
            Color.purple
            
            //Display the Text view.
            ResponseView().glassBackgroundEffect()
        }
    }
    .windowResizability(.contentMinSize)
    .defaultSize(width: 450, height: 100)
    .windowStyle(.plain)
}

struct ResponseView: View {
    @State private var responseText : String = "The response will show here."
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(responseText)
                .animation(.spring)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                //.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true) //I add this in to get the text to flow upwards like in the video but this makes the text flow past the bounds.
                //.frame(minHeight: 100, maxHeight: 1000) //This when added here or on the vstack did not grow or work either. It looked like it may make the text frame bigger but now the window.
            
            //Some other conditional views that will appear when certain permissions or no internet connection is detected.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think you want to resize the window but rather a view within the window needs to resize and that view should have a `.glassBackgroundEffect()` view modifier. Set the window style to .`plain` to remove the default glass effect of the window. Then apply glass effect to a view.

However, what you likely need is a scroll view but with the scrolling invert like in a messaging app. That way when text overflows you can still scroll up to see what was added before. To do this you need to use a `PreferenceKey` to send size changes up the view hierarchy.

For example:

```
struct HeightKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGSize? = nil

    static func reduce(value: inout CGSize?, nextValue: () -> CGSize?) {
        value = value ?? nextValue()
    }
}

@main
struct MyGrowingWindowApp: App {
    @State var text = "Some text to start with"
    @State var scrollViewHeight: CGFloat = 0.0
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 2, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ZStack {
                ScrollView {
                    VStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Text(text)
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .foregroundStyle(.white)
                            .frame(maxWidth: 600, alignment: .leading)
                            .padding()
                            .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                                text += " More text please :o)"
                            }
                            .animation(.default, value: text)
                        
                    }
                    // Rotating and flipping scroll view content so it appears correct
                    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 180))
                    .scaleEffect(x: -1.0, y: 1.0, anchor: .center)
                    .padding()
                    .overlay(GeometryReader{ geometry in
                        Color.clear.preference(key: HeightKey.self, value: geometry.size)
                    })
                    .onPreferenceChange(HeightKey.self, perform: { value in
                        self.scrollViewHeight = value?.height ?? 0.0
                    })
                    
                }
                // rotating and flipping the scroll view will invert
                .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 180))
                .scaleEffect(x: -1.0, y: 1.0, anchor: .center)
                .frame(maxHeight: 200, alignment: .bottom)
                .mask {
                    // Apply mask if we're at our max height
                    if scrollViewHeight >= 200 {
                        LinearGradient(stops: [.init(color: .white, location: 0.0), .init(color: .white, location: 0.5), .init(color: .white.opacity(0.6), location: 0.7), .init(color: .clear, location: 1.0)], startPoint: .bottom, endPoint: .top)
                            .frame(height: 200)
                    } else {
                        Color.white
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(height: min(scrollViewHeight, 200), alignment: .bottom)
            .background(.purple.opacity(0.5))
            .glassBackgroundEffect()
            .animation(.default, value: scrollViewHeight)
        }
        .windowStyle(.plain)
        .defaultSize(width: 500, height: 200)
    }
}
```

Should give you an effect like this:

[image: Growing glass backed view in window]

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! This works exactly like the gif and is what I needed! Do you mind explaining how some things work? Specifically, I don't understand the preference key portion, the .mask, the .overlay, and the linear gradient with the different opacity of whites.